# Fitting normally distributed wine into normally distributed casks

Tags: probability, statistics

The amount, $A$, of wine in a bottle $\sim N(1.05l,0.004l^2)$ (Note: $l$ means liters.)

b) Casks are available which have a volume, $V$, which is $N(22l,0.16l^2)$. What is the probability the contents of 20 randomly chosen bottles will fit inside a randomly chosen cask?

The cask volumes are random, but so are the wine volumes. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a very useful result about the normal distribution.  Let  $X$ and $Y$ be **independent** normals, with means $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ and variances $\sigma_X^2$ and $\sigma_Y^2$. Let $a$ and $b$ be **any** constants.

Then $aX+bY$ has **normal** distribution, with mean $a\mu_X+b\mu_Y$, and variance $a^2\sigma_X^2+b^2 \sigma_Y^2$.

To apply the result to the wine, let random variables $W_1, W_2,\dots, W_{20}$ be the volume of wine contained in bottles $1,2,\dots,20$. Let $V$ be the volume of the cask. Consider the random variable $(W_1+W_2+\cdots+W_{20})-V$. This is of the form $aX+bY$, where $a=1$ and $b=-1$.

**Question:** Why are we transferring wine **from** bottles **to** a cask? That's not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Under suitable missing independence hypotheses the OP will soon add to the question, the random variable $V-(A_1+\cdots+A_{20})$ is gaussian $\mathcal N(m,\sigma^2)$ for some parameters $m$ and $\sigma^2$ to be determined. Thus the probability that $V-(A_1+\cdots+A_{20})$ is nonnegative is $P[m+\sigma Z\geqslant0]$, where $Z$ is standard normal, that is, $\Phi\left(\frac{m}\sigma\right)$.

A useful result will be that, if $X$ is normal $\mathcal N(m,\sigma^2)$ and $Y$ normal $\mathcal N(n,\tau^2)$ and if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $X+Y$ is normal $\mathcal N(m+n,\sigma^2+\tau^2)$.